# Which windows account is used to upload files to SharePoint document library?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, workflow, document-library

I am using the following code

```
    WindowsIdentity wIdb4 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    string name = wIdb4.Name;
```

in a workflow to show which user account is being used to upload a document. When i write the above mentioned string in a workflow history event, it always returns NETWORK SERVICE, even if i am logged in using the site collection administrator. Can anyone tell me why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.Name
```

EDIT:

I figured there may not be an associated SPContext in your workflow.

What does he following resolve to within your workflow?

```
workflowProperties.OriginatorUser
```

Comment: will it be different than the way above mentioned?? if yes, why will it be different?

Comment: Yes. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() will always return the Process identity (i.e. NETWORK SERVICE)

Comment: strange enough ... on my dev machine i get a NullReference exception on using SPCOntext.Current ... 
When i debug it says SPContext.Current is null...can you tell me why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow will always run as a service account (typically the IIS Application Pool account)

Comment: actually the application pool account is a user called xyz\myusername

where xyz is my domain and myusername is the windows account...still the workflow shows current user as the network service